# SQL / Postgresql count multiple columns with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, multiple-columns, postgresql-12

I have a simple table of the form:

| id | gender | a_feature (bool) | b_feature (bool) | ... | xyz_feature (bool) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

and I want to sum over all feature columns dependent on gender.

| metric | male | female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_feature | 345 | 3423 |
| b_feature | 65 | 143 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| xyz_feature | 133 | 5536 |

Is there a simple way to do this, e.g. using the information_schema.

I found only the solution below, but this is very ugly:

```
select
       'a_feature' as feature_name,
       count(case a_feature and gender = 'male') as male,
       count(case a_feature and gender = 'female') as female
from table
union
select
       b_feature as feature_name,
       count(case b_feature and gender = 'male') as male,
       count(case b_feature and gender = 'female') as female
from table
.
.
.
select
       xyz_feature as feature_name,
       count(case xyz_feature and gender = 'male') as male,
       count(case xyz_feature and gender = 'female') as female
from table
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The code you have is not syntactically valid either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate.  One method is:

```
select name,
       sum(case when feature and gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as num_male,
       sum(case when feature and gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as num_female
from ((select 'a_feature' as name, a_feature as feature, gender
       from t
      ) union all
      (select 'b_feature' as name, b_feature, gender
       from t
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) f
group by name;
```

In Postgres, you would unpivot using a lateral join:

```
select name,
       sum(case when feature and gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as num_male,
       sum(case when feature and gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as num_female
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('a_feature', a_feature),
             ('b_feature', b_feature),
             . . .
     ) v(name, feature)
group by name;
```

You can generate the list for `values()` using `information_schema.columns` if you are reluctant to type it all in.

EDIT:

You can construct the `values` clause using something like this:

```
select string_agg('(''' || column_name || ''', column_name)', ', ') 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = ?
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is what i was looking for!

Comment: Dear Gordon, can you please draft an example how to use the information_schema.columns, to get a dynamic query?

Answer (score 0):

When you use this in Postgres, what do you mean by **t** (I think t is for table) in   *"from t cross join lateral"* and what do you mean by **v** in *"v(name, feature)"* ?

```
select name,

           sum(case when feature and gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as num_male,
           sum(case when feature and gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as num_female
    from t cross join lateral
         (values ('a_feature', a_feature),
                 ('b_feature', b_feature),
                 . . .
         ) v(name, feature)
    group by name;
```